# Internal Server Error when passing parameters to WCF service

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, wcf, .net-3.5

I'm messing about with my first WCF service and I am having problems passing parameters.

My jQuery ajax call looks like this...

```
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    async   : true,
    url     : 'Service2.svc/GetStats',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data    : '{ i : 12 }',
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(result) {
        //success routine...
    }
});
```

add my service code is like...

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetStats(ByVal i As Integer) As Results
    Dim returnValue As New Results
    returnValue.iValue1 = 10
    returnValue.iValue2 = 20
    returnValue.sMessage = "You executed " + "sdfsd"
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

`Results` class is a really simple holder class, two Integers and a String.

This service works fine if I remove the parameters from `GetStats` and remove the corresponding `data` property from my $.ajax object - I can access the three returned values on the client.

When the parameter `i` is included I get an `Internal Server Error` status:500.

I'm guessing I'm missing an attribute or something from my service Function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.

I spent a while wrestling with this one and all I needed to do was...

```
        data    : '{"i" : 12}' ,  //Object name i in double-quotes
```

So contrary to some of the other suggestions i *do* want to pass the JSON as a string. (I suppose one should really use a library such as [Crockford's JSON](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for this)

However I could only discover this after finding what the actual error was. I did this by throwing this snippet into my `web.config` file...

```
<system.diagnostics>
  <sources>
    <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing"
      propagateActivity="true">
      <listeners>
        <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
        <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
          <filter type="" />
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </source>
  </sources>
  <sharedListeners>
    <add initializeData="app_tracelog.svclog"
      type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, 
        Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
      <filter type="" />
    </add>
  </sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I got this from [mkdot.net](http://mkdot.net/mknetug/b/dejan/archive/2008/10/23/wcf-tracing-and-message-logging.aspx) and it should really be generated using SvcConfigEditor.exe - which I couldn't find on my locked down machine. But just pasting that in seemed to work - and gave me a log file in my development folder - this actually told me the nature of the error.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to send data as string. you have to send it as an object.

```
data    : { i : 12 },
```

---

umm. it does not work on this.

try this.

```
data: 'i=12';
```

change your service like this and try again.

```
<OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)> _
Public Function GetStats(ByVal i As String) As Results
    Dim returnValue As New Results
    returnValue.iValue1 = 10
    returnValue.iValue2 = 20
    returnValue.sMessage = "You executed " + "sdfsd"
    Return returnValue
End Function
```

Comment: @ElRonnoco I'm not familiar with vb but there is nothing wrong with your ajax call. Have you tried staticly call your service with a paremter? there should be a syntax error or st.

Comment: @ElRonnoco I think, umm, you are sending data via js. so integer changing to string. And you are trying to get parameter as integer. maybe you have to get paramter as string and then convert it to integer in method..

Comment: `'i=12'` does not work sorry. Static (Shared in VB) call work from within Page Init event. Changing parameter type to `Object` gives same error also...

Comment: change parameter type to String. if still does not work, I'm going home :P

Comment: Thanks littlealien, you can go home :(

Answer (score 0):

you should do

```
var data = { i : 12 };

$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    async   : true,
    url     : 'Service2.svc/GetStats',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data    : data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(result) {
        //success routine...
    }
});
```

you are sending data as a string, while it should be an object